# Equation of a plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have attempted this question and simply wish for confirmation of my process and answer. My university does not offer memos for past examinations.(Where I got the question from.)

The question is as follows:
Compute the equation of the plane parallel to **v** and **w** and passing through the tip of **u**.

Where u=(2,0,1) v=(2,3,0) and w=(0,2,2)

So from the info from the question I have made 2 assumptions:

1. Since **v** and **w** are parallel to the plane, their normal vector is also normal to the plane.
2. The "tip" of **u**'s point has the value of the vector itself.(poorly worded)

From this I obtained the normal vector of **v** and **w** using the cross product and obtained (6,4,-4)

Then I subbed the normal and point into the formula 
a(x-x1)+b(y-y1)+c(z-z1)=0

Finally i obtained 6x+4y-4z-8=0 (I don't believe I should simplify?)

Any feedback or extra helpful theory is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the points and what are the vectors?

Comment: The vectors I listed just below the question. u,v and w. The point wasnt given explicitly and was given as the statement i presume "passes through the tip of [the vector] u".

Comment: So $u,v,w$ are vectors?

Comment: Indeed they are.

Comment: The cross product is $v\times w=\begin{pmatrix}6\\-4\\4\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $\langle\begin{pmatrix}6\\-4\\4\end{pmatrix},(\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{pmatrix})\rangle=0$ gives you the equation

Comment: sorry yes i was copying this from paper where i mistakenly switched 4 and -4

Comment: That happens! The equation is $6x-4y+4z=16$

Comment: Or equivalently $3x-2y+2z=8$

Comment: ah ok. So indeed, I am to simplify. Is it necessary to have it in that form or is leaving it equal to 0 also acceptable?

Comment: That is of course also acceptable!

Comment: Thank you my post is answered.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: “The equation” is ambiguous. Presumably they’re asking for an implicit Cartesian equation of the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i would write $$\vec{x}=[2,0,1]+\alpha[0,3,-1]+\beta[-2,2,1]$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ are real numbers

Comment: Thank you for the input. However. I do not understand. Are these parameters for x?

Comment: This is an equation of a plane in parameter form

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.